# Double conditional filtering of many csv files in python

Tags: python, duplicates

I stack into the following task: combine all files under specific mask and remove duplicates based on two criteria: if the `name` and `TEXT` are identical keep the one with the largest 4th column.

I currently have this not well tested code (based on my previous question), but because it's using dictionary, it rewriting the previous data that has the same name but different TEXT. I was trying to use only lists.

How to make the filtering on two conditions simultaneously?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import glob,csv
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
fo = open("combined.csv","a")
writer = csv.writer(fo,delimiter=' ')

datum = []
nyt = set()

for f in files:
    with open(f) as fi:
        for row in csv.reader(fi,delimiter=' '):
            crow = row[0],row[4]
            nyt.add(crow)
            if crow in nyt:
                dupl = [element for element in datum if element[0] == row[0]]
                if dupl[0][3] < row[3]:
                    # replace row in datum with row
                if dupl[0][3] > row[3]:
                    continue
            else:
                datum.append(row)
```

examples

```
file1      
name1 0.06 0.91 0.17 TEXT1 smthing smthing
name2 0.46 0.42 0.02 TEXT1 smthing smthing
name3 0.15 0.80 0.61 TEXT1 smthing smthing
file2      
name1 0.68 0.38 0.61 TEXT2 smthing smthing
name2 0.73 0.62 0.03 TEXT2 smthing smthing
name3 0.84 0.81 0.60 TEXT2 smthing smthing
file3      
name1 0.86 0.18 0.03 TEXT1 smthing smthing
name2 0.04 0.12 0.75 TEXT1 smthing smthing
name3 0.59 0.70 0.71 TEXT1 smthing smthing
```

Comment: Regarding `if crow in nyt`: One line above this you added `crow` to `nyt` so it is then always contained in it. To replace an item in a list you need its index, therefore read about the `index`-method of the list type

Comment: I combined the values as a unique key

Comment: @JohnAmraph Remember to accept your own answer when it will let you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking too much, the fast solution is to combine two values as a unique key for the dict

```
import glob,csv
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
fo = open("combined.csv","a")
writer = csv.writer(fo,delimiter=' ')

datum = {}

for f in files:
    with open(f) as fi:
        for row in csv.reader(fi,delimiter=' '):
            crow = row[0],row[4]
            if crow in datum:
                if float(datum[crow][-4]) < float(row[3]):
                    datum[crow] = row[0:]
            else:
                datum[crow] = row[0:]
```

Comment: than process just values of the dict